# CSS File is not applied to my javaFX code - "Unknown property"

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am new to JavaFX and I was just getting started with css. I wrote everything and now the warnings show "Unknown property: "-fx-background-size""(for example). And nothing of the css file is applied to my javafx code.

I am using jdk-10.0.2 and jre1.8.0_261.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            // Root Node -Layout der Szene, HBox horizontal
            HBox root = new HBox();
            root.setPrefSize(340.0, 70.0);
            root.setSpacing(10.0);
            root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            // Elemente erstellen wie Button
            Button button1 = new Button();
            Button button2 = new Button();
            Button button3 = new Button();
            Button button4 = new Button();
            Button button5 = new Button();

            // Button Größe
            button1.setPrefSize(64.0, 64.0);
            button2.setPrefSize(64.0, 64.0);
            button3.setPrefSize(64.0, 64.0);
            button4.setPrefSize(64.0, 64.0);
            button5.setPrefSize(64.0, 64.0);

            

            

            button1.getStyleClass().add("button1");
            button2.getStyleClass().add("button2");
            button3.getStyleClass().add("button3");
            button4.getStyleClass().add("button4");
            button5.getStyleClass().add("button5");

            // Elemente zum root Node hinzufügen
            root.getChildren().add(button1);
            root.getChildren().add(button2);
            root.getChildren().add(button3);
            root.getChildren().add(button4);
            root.getChildren().add(button5);

            // Elemente klickbar machen - Eventhandling

            // Szene erstellen
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```css
 /* JavaFX CSS - Leave this comment until you have at least create one rule which uses -fx-Property */

.button1 {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-background-size: 64.0 64.0;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center;
}

.button2 {
    -fx-background-image: url(".../images/facebook.png");
    -fx-background-size: 64.0 64.0;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center;
}

.button3 {
    -fx-background-image: url(".../images/twitter.png");
    -fx-background-size: 64.0 64.0;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center;
}

.button4 {
    -fx-background-image: url(".../images/amazon.png");
    -fx-background-size: 64.0 64.0;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center;
}

.button5 {
    -fx-background-image: url(".../images/exit.png");
    -fx-background-size: 64.0 64.0;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center;
}
```

I wrote the css part in a different file and included: scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
Can you guys help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: of course nothing happens if the css file is erroneous. The error message is pretty clear. Remove the line "-fx-background-size" then try again...

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're using JDK 10 and JRE 8? I would expect that to end up with an `UnsupportedClassVersionError`. In any case, your syntax seems correct according to the [_JavaFX CSS Reference Guide_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region). Note it says "px" will be used if no unit is specified but maybe there's a bug; what happens when you explicitly add units to your numbers?

Comment: @Joe   Hey thanks for the anwser. I tried to remove the line but nothing changed

Comment: @Slaw I checked the preferences -> java -> installed JREs and also the enviroment variables (idk if it's the english word for it) but both said 10.0.2